# WPF C# - multiple CheckBox controls in a DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, list, checkbox, datagrid

In the DataGrid control I would like to add a column in which each cell would contain a list of checkbox controls (for each cell there can be a different number of such checkboxes with different descriptions). I don't know how to define such a column with an undefined number of checkboxes in a cell.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try to do to solve your problem? Provide the code example, please.

Comment: I thought about it a bit and got the idea of ​​using a ListBox in a DataGridTemplate.

Comment: Would a treeview suit this better than a datagrid?

Answer (score 2):

I was curious how this would look so I put something together for you.  Hopefully the comments are enough to push you in the right direction.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="multipleCheckBoxControlsDatagrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:multipleCheckBoxControlsDatagrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!--DataTemplate for "listbox of checkboxes" column. Checks is a property on the ItemsSource of type DataGridRowData.  Check is a property on the ItemsSource of type DataGridCellData -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Checks}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Check}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridDataCollection}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--Custom column that contains a listbox of checkboxes-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Checks" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace multipleCheckBoxControlsDatagrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // PropertyChanged event so the datagrid get updated when DataGridDataCollection changes
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // the datagrid binds to this collection
        private ObservableCollection<DataGridRowData> _DataGridDataCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<DataGridRowData> DataGridDataCollection
        {
            get => _DataGridDataCollection;
            set
            {
                _DataGridDataCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataGridDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRowData>();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            addChecks();
        }

        // adds data to the DataGrid
        private void addChecks()
        {
            DataGridDataCollection.Add(new DataGridRowData(new List<bool> { true, false, true }));
            DataGridDataCollection.Add(new DataGridRowData(new List<bool> { false, true, false, false, true }));
            DataGridDataCollection.Add(new DataGridRowData(new List<bool> { false, true, false, false, true, false, true }));
        }


        // PropertyChanged event so the datagrid get updated when DataGridDataCollection changes
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    // this class represents one row of data in the data grid
    // there is one column in this row named Checks
    // the column is a list of DataGridCellData
    // the listbox in each DataGrid cell binds to this
    public class DataGridRowData
    {
        public List<DataGridCellData> Checks { get; set; }

        public DataGridRowData(List<bool> checks)
        {
            Checks = new List<DataGridCellData>();
            foreach(bool b in checks)
            {
                Checks.Add(new DataGridCellData(b));
            }
        }
    }

    // this class represents one unit of data in the above listbox
    // so each cell in the DataGrid is bound to a ListBox and this class represents one line of data in that listbox
    public class DataGridCellData
    {
        public bool Check { get; set; }
        public DataGridCellData(bool check)
        {
            Check = check;
        }
    }
}
```